# Put a resistor in series between amp and speaker

Tags: amplifier, resistors, audio, sound, class-d

I use a [PAM8403 class-D amplifier module](http://static.sunrom.com/p/846/846_0_800.jpg) (~ 2$ on ebay), which is very good, and stereo.

The output volume is too loud. If I lower the amp's *input* volume (via software), then obvisouly the output volume is lowered, but there's a noise buzz.
That's why I would like to lower the output volume rather than the input volume.

I noticed randomly that **putting a 10k resistor** in series between OUT+ and loudspeaker's input **makes the volume lower**.

It works, I am quite happy with that. But:

1) **Is it a good practice?** Why does it work?

2) This 10k resistor seems (by ear) to make something like -20dB volume reduction.
**Is there a formula to find R for -10dB reduction?**

Here is how it looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGMKRc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PS: I don't know my earphones's impedance but I can say it's [standard earphones](https://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/e/h/f/samsung_ehs61asfwe_in_ear_earphones_white__19462_800x800-129c3.jpg) shipped with my Samsung phone.

Comment: PS: 1k resistor instead of 10k seems correct (closer to 10dB volume reduction)

Comment: PS2: it seems that there is a small distorsion, though, like very small crunch/clipping

Comment: Attenuate the input with a voltage divider (2 resistors) or a volume control (pot) rather than software.

Comment: Yes, but as there is a constant noise floor on the output of PAM8403 (even if IN+ = IN - = GND), I wanted to diminish the volume of output to make the noise floor diminish as well. What do you think @BrianDrummond ?

Comment: You need a voltage divider (pot).  The noise you're getting might be Johnson–Nyquist noise - the "sound" of a signal through the resistor, or it might be a noisy power supply, which would call for bypass caps.

Comment: @tjbtech : When I power the PAM8403 with RaspberryPi's 5V (itself coming from phone microUSB power supply), output is quite noisy.  When I power the PAM8403 with RPi's 3.3V, it's far better. But still a background white noise floor... (even when INPUT is silence, ie IN+=IN-). Would you have an answer with how to do it with bypass caps (I tried things but maybe I did it wrong)? I'm pulling my hair off since days with this :)

Comment: I see.  The noise was there to begin with.  If swapping the supply to another lessened noise significantly, it's likely the module's own filtering isn't sufficient (the amp was two bucks, after all).  A bypass capacitor would just sit between V+ and ground as close to the module as possible, and you'd use a fairly large electrolytic.  Audio circuits are also quite susceptible to RF interference, but I would start by adding the capacitor and seeing how far it gets you.

Comment: @tjbtech A 10uF electrolytic cap between 5V and GND  of PAM8403 power supply? I tried a 10uF, 100uF, it didn't change anything

Comment: Yup, that'll work.  Also, do you have coupling capacitors on the input lines?  Ideally, you'd use an audio transformer to isolate the input source since your input has single-ended/unbalanced output going into a single-ended input, but if you're not properly filtering the signal, that would explain everything.  In retrospect, it seems likely to be responsible for most of the remainder of your noise.

Comment: When amp is powered by dirty 5V : 10uF cap: doesn't change anything. 100uF cap: improves a little bit (hearable) the noise.

// When amp is powered by clean 3.3V : 10uF cap: doesn't change anything. 100uF cap: doesn't change anything.

Comment: I thought the audio on a raspberry pi was based on a GPIO PWM DAC, not great to begin with. Choosing the best ground reference is just as critical as the supply rail.

Comment: I'm not using the RPi built in sound, but a good DAC via i2c @sstobbe

Comment: Will your dac module not directly drive a set of headphones or is it a custom design? How are you connecting your DAC to the class-d amp?

Comment: @sstobbe no the DAC produces line level output I think, and so a headphones amp is needed

Answer (score 2):

Cheap class D amplifiers have very poor rejection of power supply noise/ripple. This is fully expected because the output square wave peak **IS** the power rail so, the trick is to make that power rail as quiet as possible. So, if your output signal is quite small, noise/ripple on the power rails can dominate.

> This 10k resistor seems (by ear) to make something like -20dB volume
>   reduction. Is there a formula to find R for -10dB reduction?

A 20 dB volume reduction is about a 4:1 decrease in sound level as perceived by the ear because 10 dB (or 1 bel) is "defined" as the attenuation that halves loudness at 1 kHz. This doesn't hold true for other audio frequencies but it's a good measure.

If your loudness has reduced by 4 then that is an attenuation of 20 dB. If your earphones have an impedance of about 1000 ohm then adding a 10 k resistor will attenuate the signal to 1000/11000 = 0.09 and if you take the log and multiply by 20 you get 20.82 dB.